# transformer - can it also be connected to 24v ac

Tags: transformer

if the a transformer can lower the voltage from 230 to 12v ac @ certain amount of current, given the same transformer can you give it say 24vac and still get a proportional output on the secondary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If the transformer produces 12 V from 230 V, then it will produce 1.25 V from 24 V.  It will be grossly overspecced for 24 V in, so will be heavier and more expensive than at transformer intended for the same 24 V in at the same power level.

Comment: cool just curious. I thought it would work since it just uses induction.

Comment: @Ageis - BUT !!!!!!!!!!!! it does NOT work the other way :-). You may not apply a HIGHER voltage to a winding than it is rated at. (A VERY small % over-voltage may be Ok but not much.)